# Android : "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" after migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, signing

I've been developing my project in Eclipse IDE. The app is submitted on Play Store, and I've published a couple of versions updates successfully.

Recently I've migrated to Android Studio (and gradle, of course). I've done some changes to the project code base, including min and target sdk changes, but package name remains the same. The project is successfully compiled and debug app is successfully assembled and running ok.

But now I can not assemble a release version because of :

```
Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

The keystore have not changed, and I do know it's password.

I've set signingconfigs in build.gradle:

```
android {
  ...
  signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("keystore/motolife.keystore")
        storePassword "***"
        keyAlias "motolife"
        keyPassword "***"
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I've tried also to sign using jarsigner:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore keystore/motolife.keystore build/outputs/apk/motolife-new-debug.apk motolife
```

But no luck.
I've even installed gradle support for Eclipse and tried to assemble signed release app , but got the same "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" error.

Comment: does your password have any complex characters in it?  I have seen having commas in it causes issues.

Comment: @reidisaki, password is alpha-numeric, plus "@" symbol

Comment: is it possible to try and create a keystore with a simple password without the @? I've seen people having issues with non alpha-numeric symbols when migrating.

Comment: @reidisaki, I can not even change a password for my keystore, because of that error. And creating a new keystore is not an option for me.

Comment: @alexaschka Have you got any solution for your issue? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this then:

```
    release {
        storeFile file("keystoreName.keystore") //change value per signing
         def pass = System.console().readPassword("\nPlease enter key password: ")   
        pass = new String(pass)
        storePassword pass
        keyAlias "revision3" //need to change these values per signing
        keyPassword pass            
    }
```